# let users add multiple divs in static page

Tags: customization

I'm pretty new to wordpress and I'm using twentytwelve as a theme. I've created a very simple custom template for some pages:

```
<?php /* Template Name: New Test page*/ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and what I'd like to do is when they create a page using this template is to give them the possibility to add as many  just by clicking a button or using a repeater, something like that. Basically what I'm saying is that I don't want users to mess around with the HTML - as they don't know how to code - just to be able to add predefined containers that I've created for them and that are tied to the template they've selected. Is that doable? If so how? I've been looking into it for a little while, researching different plugins like piklist etc but I don't seem to be able to find what I want

Comment: Everything is possible - depends on your approach and expertise. BTW it's nothing related to WordPress, and off-topic here in WPSE. :(

Comment: sorry I thought this was for wordpress dev support, including customizing templates?

Comment: Where are your users editing? Front end or back end?